# Object update inside ArrayList

Tags: java

How can I get the second object from an arrayList of type (class)Person and apply a method to that particular object?

```
ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

For ex. I have a method in Person class called hasBirthday() which add one year to the object person but it applies only to the second Object created. This in order to display a message of happy birthday and add one year once the second object is created from the console. After all we like birthdays ;)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "it applies only to the second Object created"? (I question the wisdom of designing a `hasBirthday` method that mutates state, too... that sounds like it just *checks* something and returns an answer.)

Comment: If there is a second object in the array, the method hasBirthday will be called and update the object by one extra year(of age)and a message to let the user know of the changes. Yes more or less like giving an answer to the program for the second object and a notification to the user for the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean this:

```
person.get(1).hasBirthday();
```

that will call hasBirthday method on the second object in the list (if it exists).

Comment: Great! I was close with person.get(1), let me try the rest to see how I manage. thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks once again!

Comment: Glad it is fine. Next time I encourage you to search simply the structure/method you need help with, like "java arraylist". Java's docummentation is quite rich and nearly always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
person.add(new Person(someParam1));
person.add(new Person(someParam2));
person.add(new Person(someParam3));

if (person.size() >= 2) {
    Person secondPerson = person.get(1);
    secondPerson.hasBirthday();
}
```

Comment: Thing is that the user will add the info from the console and the array will update itself the info. The last part was the one I was looking for though. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a safe way to do that:

```
if(person.size() >1 && person.get(1) != null){
    person.get(1).hasBirthday();
}
```

This checks the `List` is of proper length, and the value at that index is not null.

I'd rename your `hasBirthday` method to something like `increaseAge`, or a setter to assign age, like `setAge` if age is something you allow to be assigned. Descriptive method names are useful.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with a few changes. I was close missing the .hasBirthday part. Thanks for the answer!